# VBA to connect Oracle DB

Tags: database, vba, oracle

I'm using below code in VBA (macro) to connect Oracle DB.
I'm getting error as

> Run-time error '3706':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

Please help me any other setting to do

```vb
Sub ConnectToOracle()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mtxData As Variant


Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open ( _
    "User ID=cadcaguser" & _
    ";Password=cadcaguser11" & _
    ";Data Source=macroToDB" & _
    ";Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")


'Clean upin the end

Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you reference the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects .. Library"? Did you install the `Oracle OLE DB` provider? Did you install an Oracle Client?

Comment: And always tell in which line you get an error.